# In assasin creed 4 can we fast travel within cities?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

For example, rather than running from places to places, I saw many fast travel icons on the map. Can I fast travel there?

I know I can fast travel to save sailing time. What about if I am not sailing? Why are they so many fast travel icons on one city? If fast travel is only when sailing, then we need only one fast travel icons per city right?

I am using PS4. In world map, I can fast travel with square key. What button I should press if I am within a city. I select a fast travel icon, press square, nothing happen.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes. I've tried selecting the fast travel icon and press square in PS3. Nothing happened. Is it a different button? In world map, that's what I use.

Comment: Here I saw http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zikdRZDles . That's world fast travel. What about within city fast travel? I look at google looking for "within city fast travel assasin creed" can't fight it.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking here if I didn't try and fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is where the confusion start.

Within city, you can fast travel to **synchronize** point. You cannot fast travel to "fast travel" point.

What you can do is you go by foot to "fast travel" points and you will have an option to teleport to another "fast travel" points.

The fast travel points look like small boats that usually teleport us to our ship. Instead, it teleport us to other fast travel points.

Answer (score 10):

Fast travel can be done to any fast travel icon that you have unlocked by synchronizing at. This will then take you to that fast travel icon. If it is in a city it will take you to that point. If you are already in the city you can still use it.

Comment: There are many fast travel icon in a city. I select it and press what? The fast travel button in world map doesn't work.

Comment: Using PS4. The square button works in world map. It doesn't work for fast travel icons in the city.

Comment: I've not got a PS4 but I'm pretty sure that on the xbox its the same for all fast travel points. Have you definitely unlocked the fast travel point you are looking at?

Comment: I saw the fast travel icons

Comment: You need to actually go and synchronize at them (there was a tutorial one on this somewhere near the beginning I think) to unlock them. If you haven't done that then you won't be able to use them.

Comment: Synchronize with high point or with fast travel points? Would you update your answer?

Comment: There is no difference between high points and fast travel points. The high points *are* fast travel points. I will update to clarify that by unlock I mean synchronize.

Comment: That's exactly where the confusion is. There are icons in the map labeled fast travel points instead of synchronize points.

Comment: @JimThio: Hmmm... I'll have to go look...